# How to make one function wait for a callback of another function?

Tags: objective-c

I have two functions:
function A sends a request to the server side and have a callback to handle the response. at certain point, for example, a webpage starts loading, it's triggered.
function B is a normal function, at certain point, for example when a webpage finishes loading, it's triggered.
Function A is triggered before function B. so that means, when B is executing, A has already started.
but I want function B to wait for the callback in A to finish, and then continue execution. 
I want to know how to implement this?

I've read about semaphores and NSCondition, but the examples are all about parent thread and child thread. In my case, they are independent of each other.

Comment: Don't wait. Use completion blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Please, try with completion blocks.
Follow this code structure...

```
-(void)serverRequestFetchData:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request withCallback:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))aCallback {

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSHTTPURLResponse *statusResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if (statusResponse.statusCode >= 200 && statusResponse.statusCode < 300) {
        if (data.length > 0 && error == nil) {
        NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        if (aCallback) {
        aCallback(array, nil);
        }
        } else {
        aCallback(@[], error);
        }
        } else {
        NSString *statusMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invalid status response code: %ld", (unsigned long)statusResponse.statusCode];
        NSError *statusError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.somedomain" code:10001 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString(statusMessage, nil)}];
        if (aCallback) {
        aCallback(@[], statusError);
        }
        }
        });
        }];
    [dataTask resume];

}

-(void)myRequest {

    NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"access_token\":\"ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE\"}"];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_FIRST_URL_STRING"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    [self serverRequestFetchData:request withCallback:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_SECOND_URL_STRING"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

        [self serverRequestFetchData:request withCallback:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {

        }];
        }];

}
```